# Using combining accents as an automatic fallback?

Tags: pdf, unicode, diacritical-mark

I am using lots of diacritics (mostly accents and diareses/umlauts, the occasional cedilla or ogonek) in my documents. Almost all of them are supported fine: I enter them directly using Unicode and all is good.

The other day I would have needed **Ȧ** (U+0226 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOT ABOVE): A glyph that is not supported by my font of choice. Using **`\.{A}`** worked fine, however. Is that a shorthand for using **A+◌̇** (U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE) or does `(La)TeX` draw the dot itself, as it were? Do, say, **`\.{Z}`** and **`Ż`** (which exists as a precomposed glyph), or **`\"{A}`** and **`Ä`** for that matter, produce the same glyph? Can you tell from the compiled PDF which method was used in the source?

Finally: Is there a way to instruct (La)TeX (any flavor, any engine) to use these automatically as a fallback instead of showing the dreaded � (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)?

Comment: that depends on the tex engine you are using, and the current font encoding

Comment: LuaLaTeX by default, but open to anything else if needed. Encoding: UTF-8 always & everywhere. Also, standard .otf and .ttf fonts.

Comment: see discussion of fake or not accents `texdoc fontspec` page 53

Comment: Thanks, will do.